# How to get the C column corresponding values according to B columns pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have this table:

[image]

How to get the  C  column corresponding values according to B columns?

Let's say, Now I have `red`, How to get `bear` value? I have `dog`, how to get `snake`?
I would like a in-built method not by counting.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Did you try using `pd.DataFrame.where()`? Like `df["a"].where(df["b"] == "pear")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the following *Series*:

```
s = pd.Series(df.c.tolist(), index=df.b)
```

For your case it is:

```
b
dog      snake
grape     pear
bear       red
dtype: object
```

As you can see,

- the index is from *b* column,
- values are from *c* column.

Then, when you run e.g.: `s['dog']` the result is `'snake'`.

You retrieve a value from this *Series* (containing values from *c* column),
indexing it with a value from *b* column.

Or, if you need a more general mechanism, create a *DataFrame* with
index taken from *b* column:

```
df2 = df.set_index('b')
```

For your data, the result is:

```
           a      c
b                  
dog      cat  snake
grape  apple   pear
bear   panda    red
```

Then you can use *loc*, e.g. calling `df2.loc['dog', 'c']`
will get `'snake'` (but you can also pass another column name).